# XSLT - Get String between commas

Tags: xslt

How can I get the value 'four' in XSLT?

```
<root>
  <entry>(one,two,three,four,five,six)</entry>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, which XSLT processor, which version of XSLT can you use?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to test whether the `<entry>` element has the value `four`? Is the idea that you might have a variable and want to test whether an element has text that contains that value? Is `four` significant, or just an example? Is the value always going to be a comma separated value within parenthesis?

Comment: The question is already anwered below, but what I meant is that I do already know that four is in the <entry> element on this exact position, 'four' is just an example, and it's always a comma separated value within parenthesis. And the XSLT version is 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the XSLT version, so I assume version **2.0**.

I also assume that word `four` is only a "marker", stating **from which place**
take the result string (between the 3rd and 4th comma).

To get the fragment you want, you can:

- Use `tokenize` function to "cut" the whole content of `entry`
  into pieces, using a comma as the cutting pattern.
- Take the fourth element of the result array.

This expression can be used e.g. in a template matching `entry`.

So the example script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ',')[4]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For your input XML it gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <entry>four</entry>
</root>
```